# Weird behavior with nested params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I'm experiencing this weird behavior with nested params.
When I try to save the form it says `Unpermitted parameter: organization_type`

For my organization type I only have a model but I don't think that should be the issue because the attributes are being handled in the user controller, per my understanding

I tried to have the attributes as organization_type (singular) in both form and controller white list but that does not work.

However, in the form, if I have `:organization_types` the field will not show up.

I'm really puzzled by this.

So as a quick recap:

- I do not have a controller for OrganizationType
- In the form I have: `:organization_type`. If I pluralize it does not show
- In the Controller white list I have: `:organization_types_attributes`
- In the User Model I have: Has_many and accepts_nested for `:organization_types_attributes`

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :organization_types
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :organization_types
end
```

Organization Types Model

```
class OrganizationType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ORG_TYPES = ['health', 'non-profit', 'foo', 'bar']
end
```

User Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  ...

  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, ..., organization_types_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :org_type, '_destroy'])
  end
```

User Form

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  ...
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :organization_type %><br>
    <%= f.fields_for :organization_type do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.select :org_type, options_for_select(OrganizationType::ORG_TYPES) %><br/>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `:organization_types` in your nested form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :organization_types do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.select :org_type, options_for_select(OrganizationType::ORG_TYPES) %><br/>
<% end %>
```

The reason that you found that the form does not show with the pluralized `organization_types` is that Rails will not render the nested attributes in the form if the user has no `organization_types` yet.  I would check out the very helpful Rails guide on [nested forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms), section 9.2.  To quote that source, which uses the example of a Person object that `has_many` addresses and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` addresses:

> When an association accepts nested attributes fields_for renders its
>   block once for every element of the association. In particular, if a
>   person has no addresses it renders nothing.
>   A common pattern is for the controller to build one or more empty
>   children so that at least one set of fields is shown to the user. The
>   example below would result in 2 sets of address fields being rendered
>   on the new person form...

Example from the guide, adapted for your controller:

```
def new   
  @user = User.new
  2.times { @user.organization_types.build}
end
```

See if that helps...

Comment: I changed my models to has_one... and follow the documentation @Ren mentioned and now it seems to be working. The 2 things I notice are. 1. my select helper is not showing the last saved. I tried this `<%= builder.select :org_type, options_for_select(OrganizationType::ORG_TYPES, :selected => @user.organization_type.org_type) %>` - 2. instead of updating the record it's creating a new one